# Plotting graph using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am having trouble in understanding the `optimize.curve_fit` function. My fitting function is a power law. But I don't know exactly what should be the second value in the plot command? First we have to call function `ff(L,v)` it will return us fitting line but we are not calling this function. How this command is working I want to know that.

```
x=Ls
y=Tc
#fitting function
def ff(L,v):
    return L**(-1/v)
pfit,perr=optimize.curve_fit(ff,x,y)
plt.plot(x,...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot` command plots x vs y values, so you have to calculate the corresponding y-values according to your defined function `ff`. Since `pfit` is returned as an array, you have to unpack the values when you call your fit function `ff`. If you know, that you have two coefficients, you could of course simply extract them like `v, k = pfit` and calculate the y-values with `ff(x, v, k)`. But what if you change the fit function later on to `L**(-1/v) * k + a`? Then you would have to rewrite your code. An easier way is to leave it to Python to unpack your coefficients with `*pfit`:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#define some sample data
x = np.arange(1, 6)
y = np.asarray([100, 37, 18, 3, 1])

#fitting function with more than one parameter to fit
def ff(L, v, k):
    return L**(-1/v) * k

pfit, perr = curve_fit(ff,x,y)
print(pfit)

#plot original data
plt.plot(x, y, "ro", label = "data")
#calculate y-values
y_fit = ff(x, *pfit)
#plot fitted curve
plt.plot(x, y_fit, "b", label = "fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is of course less than impressive, the fitted curve doesn't look smooth at all:
[image]

To overcome this, we might want to create an x-value range with a better resolution and plot this one instead of the original x-value data:

```
x_fit = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 1000)
plt.plot(x_fit, ff(x_fit, *pfit), "b", label = "fit")
```

Much better now:

[image]

Comment: Can we make changes to the scale such that curve should touch y-axis so that I can easily read value on y-axis?Can I convert this negative slope into positive one?

Comment: The negative slope is in your original data, not in the fit function itself. You can reverse the sign of v in your fit function to L**(1/v) but then the fit function would simply return -v. The first question is far from the original one, you should ask another question if you are not familiar with rescaling a graph with [plt.ylim()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html?highlight=ylim#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim) or plotting horizontal lines with [plt.axhlines()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline).

Comment: Ok I post a new question. One more thing I want to know that in fitting function you mentioned another constant that is not in power law .Why we add this constant?

Comment: Just for educational purposes so you understand easier, why we not simply extract v from pfit and feed it manually into the fit function. (And the fit function has less problems to converge for my random data set but this is a totally different problem.)