# How to create a loop to curve-fit different data sets of y for same x? in Python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matplotlib, curve-fitting

İ have 3 data sets for y axis values as follows.

```
y = [0.2535       0.3552       0.456       0.489       0.5265       0.58384  1.87616  2.87328 2.55184  2.66992  2.8208   3.09632  3.51616]
 [0.116112 0.425088 0.582528 0.70192  1.07584  2.41408  3.75232  4.61824 2.55184  2.66992  2.8208   3.09632  3.51616 ]
 [0.389664 1.166368 1.60392  2.05984  2.788    4.02784  5.0184   5.60224 2.55184  2.66992  2.8208   3.09632  3.51616 ]
```

and one data set for x values

```
x = [  0.     8.75  17.5   26.25  35.    43.75  52.5   61.25  70.    78.75
  87.5   96.25 105.  ]
```

ı am using the following command to curve fit

```
curve = np.polyfit(x, y, 4)
poly = np.poly1d(curve)
```

Which works fine for one data set of y and x. what kind of loop should ı use if ı want to have 3 different curve-fit equations for different y data sets for same x sets? ı am new to python this is why ı strugle in such a basic loop.

My expected output is an equation that represents a curve for given data sets(x and ). I managed to get an equation one by one. but. I have tons of different data sets for y and ı dont want to find the equivalent equations one by one since ı can do it in a loop for y values but dont know how?

This is the working example for one set of y values. in reality i have 3 data sets for y. ı can change the y and get 3 different results but i want to do it in a single loop for all y values

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =  [0, 5.25, 10.5, 21, 31.5, 42, 52.5, 63, 73.5, 84, 94.5, 99.75, 105]

y = [0,   0.116112, 0.389664, 1.739712, 3.566016, 4.860304, 5.05776,  5.04792,
 4.197744, 2.210064, 0.505776, 0.1312,  0]

curve = np.polyfit(x, y, 4)
poly = np.poly1d(curve)

new_x = []
new_y= []
for a in range(105):
    new_x.append(a+1)
    calc = poly(a+1)
    new_y.append(calc)
    
    plt.plot(new_x, new_y)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
print(poly)
```

Comment: Instead of the loop in your code, use `new_x = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)` and then `new_y=poly(new_x)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230301/plotting-graph-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit/51230708#51230708) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Following are some improvements of your code. I've made a function to automate the processing of your data. Do not forget that numpy provide vectorized operations so it was not usefull to iterate over new_x to get new_y. Vectorized operations are more readable and so much more performant.
I let you call the function inside a loop over your datasets.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_function(x,y):
    curve = np.polyfit(x, y, 4)
    poly = np.poly1d(curve)

    new_x = np.arange(x[0],x[-1],1)
    new_y= poly(new_x)

    plt.plot(new_x, new_y)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    print(poly)
    
x =  [0, 5.25, 10.5, 21, 31.5, 42, 52.5, 63, 73.5, 84, 94.5, 99.75, 105]

y1 = [0,   0.116112, 0.389664, 1.739712, 3.566016, 4.860304, 5.05776,  5.04792,
 4.197744, 2.210064, 0.505776, 0.1312,  0]
y2 = [0.116112 0.425088 0.582528 0.70192  1.07584  2.41408  3.75232  4.61824 2.55184  2.66992  2.8208   3.09632  3.51616 ]
y3 = [0.389664 1.166368 1.60392  2.05984  2.788    4.02784  5.0184   5.60224 2.55184  2.66992  2.8208   3.09632  3.51616 ]

ylist = [ y1, y2, y3]

for y in ylist:    
   my_function(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it know, you turned it into a function so ı can recall it for different sets of y when ı want to. ı just need to change y values.. ı also want to ask you how can ı loop with multiple y values(arrays).

Comment: `np.arange` is an inferior choice here - imagine, the last x-value was 94.5. The addressing with `x[0]` and `x[-1]` is also questionable - the x-values do not necessarily have to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me alot!!